# SSIS - Odbc source don't take dynamic variable

Tags: sql-server, ssis

How can you take a value of variable in Odbc source for sql command ?

Here what I'm doing :

[image]

My execute sql task populate my variable (ID_SCAN_CHECKPOINT)
by default the value is -2, it's int64.
[image]
[image]

After that I execute a data flow task and inside this I execute a Odbc source.

For that I built an expression :

[image]

As you can see the evaluation of the expression shows the result with the default value of my variable.

When I execute the package, I can see the value of my variable :

[image]

But my odbc source seems to use only the default value of my variable and doesn't take my new value from "Execute SQL Task"...

What did I forget here ?

Comment: What type of source are you using?   I'm not seeing an option to use an Expression with an ODBC source.

Comment: I use dataflow task > right click > Properties > Expressions

Comment: You're right clicking on the dataflow task?   I assume you're setting the property of the ODBCSource.SqlCommand property?   What are you setting it to?

Comment: yes, u're right, I set `ODBCSource.SqlCommand` property, but I resolved my issue, see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `EvaluateAsExpression` to true

Which is here (You know.... somewhere easy to find...) :

[image]

+1 if you find this useful !